# Installing ROS onto NAO V4

Tags: ros, nao-robot, cross-compiling, nao

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I've trying to install ROS Fuerte on NAO V4 with Naoqi version 1.14.2 using this [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/nao/Tutorials/Cross-Compiling_NAO-V4) . When trying to compile ROS (this is step 1.4) I succeeded in the step: $ cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$ROS_FUERTE_DIR

But now, once I run $ make -j8; the following error shows up:

Built target stereo_msgs_genpy

[ 90%] Building CXX object ros_comm/tools/rosconsole/CMakeFiles/rosconsole.dir/src/rosconsole/rosconsole.cpp.o
Linking CXX shared library ../../../lib/librosconsole.so
/home/nao/linux64-nao-atom-cross-toolchain-1.14.5/sysroot/usr/lib/liblog4cxx.so: could not read symbols: File in wrong format

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

make[2]: *** [lib/librosconsole.so] Error 1

make[1]: *** [ros_comm/tools/rosconsole/CMakeFiles/rosconsole.dir/all] Error 2

make: *** [all] Error 2

As you can see, it compiles correctly until ~90%. Doing a little research the error it appears is due to compatibility between 32 and 64 bits with the library log4cxx, but I am not completely sure. I am using a 64bits laptop (especifications are at the end of the post). Have anyone encountered this error? And know how to solve it? Thank you!

Additional info about SW and HW:

1. ROS Fuerte
2. Ubuntu 12.04.2 (64 bits)
3. Nao atom cross-toolchain 1.14.2 64bits
4. Laptop 64bits

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/70171/installing-ros-onto-nao-v4/) by [DavidLavy](https://answers.ros.org/users/2177/davidlavy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 139 on 2013-07-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

We have just released a binary distribution of ROS groovy for Nao (not fuerte, sorry).

Check it here if you wish: http://www.ros.org/wiki/nao/Installation/local

---

Originally posted by [severin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2119/severin/) with karma: 240 on 2013-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DavidLavy](https://answers.ros.org/users/2177/davidlavy/) on 2013-08-16**:
Thank you, I've already installed it and it runs smoothly ... My question is now, do you have a simple example of how to use it? The tutorials in the webpage, are more focus on either how to cross-compile or use NAO and ROS without CC

**Comment by [severin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2119/severin/) on 2013-09-20**:
Sorry for the delay... can you be more specific? what would you like to do? You may also want to open new specific questions...